# White list for Http verbs - Web.config Redirect rule

Tags: regex, web-config, redirect

I have the following redirect rule:

```
<rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(https://[^/]+/(?!api/).+)/$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

I would like to whitelist the Http verb GET and prevent any other verb from disturbing this redirect rule but I can only find documentation on how to black list verbs like so:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="POST" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />        
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="DELETE" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
```

It might look something like this:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="GET" acceptonly />
```

Comment: Did you try this `<add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="GET" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />`?

Comment: Wouldn't that ignore Get requests? I want this redirect to ONLY work on Get requests - Thank you so much for responding btw.

Comment: As long as `negate` attribute's value is `true` it ignores request methods other than `GET`.